# Embed Fonts into TileList Component; Not displaying because of Mask

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

This problem is one I have encountered before, when I mask an dynamic textfield the text disappears, in the past I have embedded fonts in order to make them appear but with a component I am unaware of how to do this. In the following code 'tf' is my text format and leftList is my TileList component. The TileList has not been created using ActionScript, it has been placed onto the stage.

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
tf.font = "Arial MT";
tf.size = 11;  
tf.align = "center";
tf.color = "0x9900ff";
tf.leading = 0;

leftList.setRendererStyle("textFormat", tf);
leftList.setStyle("embedFonts", true);
leftList.setStyle("borderStyle", "none");
leftList.setStyle("borderThickness", 0);
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i figured it out for anyone who is interested.

```
`var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.font = "Arial MT";
tf.size = 11;  
tf.align = "center";
tf.color = "0x9900ff";
tf.leading = 0;

leftList.setRendererStyle("textFormat", tf);
leftList.setStyle("embedFonts", true);
leftList.setStyle("borderStyle", "none");
leftList.setStyle("borderThickness", 0);`
```

to

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
tf.font = "Arial MT";
tf.size = 11;  
tf.align = "center";
tf.color = "0x9900ff";
tf.leading = 0;

leftList.setRendererStyle("textFormat", tf);
******leftList.setRendererStyle("embedFonts", true);**********
leftList.setStyle("borderStyle", "none");
leftList.setStyle("borderThickness", 0);
```